# par break delayed by \rlap&\smash

Tags: positioning, boxes

I use `\rlap` and `\smash` to put a little something into the left margin. Works fine unless at the beginning of a new paragraph. Then the par break happens after, not before my lap&smash construct:

```
Last line of paragraph.\par
\rlap{\smash{\hspace{-4em}Margin!}}This line should have the margin to its left.
```

[image]

Why this happens?

I can work around by putting `\strut` in front of `\rlap`. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `\rlap` nor `\llap` start a paragraph: they ultimately expand to

```
\hbox ...
```

and `\hbox` doesn't start a paragraph.

Better using

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{...}
\makebox[0pt][r]{...}
```

respectively for `\rlap` and `\llap`.

Beware that also `\smash` doesn't start a paragraph.

Comment: The surprise for me is that not even `\par` starts a paragraph.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Indeed, `\par` *ends* a paragraph. It's not like `<p>` in HTML, but rather like `</p>`.

Comment: why not use `\leavevmode`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Because it’s not in the manual.